# Fortinet configuration translation

Tags: firewall, security, fortinet

We have a small case of security breach in one of our sites, we have a contractor that is suppose to stay out of our firewall Fortinet, today i noticed these two paragraphs that look fishy. My site network administrator bailed on us few months ago and i am trying to wrap my head around these paragraphs without the need of paying someone to do it. I need your help experts!

```
> edit "Mycompany_to_Contractor"
>         set vdom "root"
>         set type tunnel
>         set snmp-index 6
>         set interface "wan1"
>     next
>     edit "Mycompany to Contractor2"
>         set vdom "root"
>         set type tunnel
>         set snmp-index 8
>         set interface "wan1"
>     next
```

Any explanation would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `edit "Mycompany...` is located under `config system interface`, this probably indicates a VPN tunnel.

Without more context it isn't possible to say if it's actually functional.

Check whether there are corresponding entries under `config vpn ipsec phase1-interface` and `config firewall policy`.

Using the GUI it should be much easier to figure out what's behind the entries.